# Workaround for pct_change not working with .rolling() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, finance, pandas-rolling

I have a dataframe that is over 2mm rows.  It has the adjusted closing prices for all of the stocks in the S&P 500 over the past 20 years (so, a mixture of companies/tickers).  The bottom section is a snapshot of my dataframe.  I will be putting this data into a predictive model that uses various momentum columns as its features and it will try to predict if a stock is likely to have a 6+% monthly return.  However, producing the appropriate "momentum columns" is proving to be difficult.

The "one_month_6_pct+_gain" column is my target & it is derived from the "21_day_performance" column.  My momentum columns can't "see" that data.

The below code works to produce columns that use information from the current row (where I don't have to shift).

```
    df['daily_performance'] = df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change().fillna(0)
    df['twenty_one_day_performance'] = df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change(periods=21).fillna(0)
    df.loc[df['twenty_one_day_performance'] >= 0.06, 'one_month_6_pct+_gain'] = "Yes"
    df.loc[df['twenty_one_day_performance'] < 0.06, 'one_month_6_pct+_gain'] = "No"
```

However, when I try to create new columns that are based on adj_close from prior days (days that don't "see" the 21 days I mentioned before), I have various problems.

This is close, but, using "sum()" here isn't correct.  If a stock is trading at $20 on day one and goes up 100% on day two it'll be at $40.  However, if it goes down 100% on day three it'll be at $0, not $20.  So, summing isn't correct here.  But it's as close to working code as I've gotten.

```
    df['preceeding_5_day_perf']=df.groupby('Ticker').daily_performance.rolling(26).sum().fillna(0).reset_index(0,drop=True)-df.groupby('Ticker').daily_performance.rolling(21).sum().fillna(0).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

I think the below would work if pct_change() was supported after rolling().  But, I get "'RollingGroupby' object has no attribute 'pct_change'"

```
    df['preceeding_5_day_perf']=df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.rolling(26).pct_change().fillna(0).reset_index(0,drop=True)-df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.rolling(21).pct_change().fillna(0).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Below throws an error. "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'RollingGroupby' and 'RollingGroupby'"

```
    df['preceeding_5_day_perf']=df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.rolling(26)-df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.rolling(21)
```

Below is close, but, it gives the negated/opposite value of "twenty_one_day_performance" for the 5 days between 21 and 26.  I'd like it to give 0.0 for those 5 days.

```
    df['preceeding_5_day_perf'] = (df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change(periods=26).fillna(0)) - (df.groupby('Ticker').adj_close.pct_change(periods=21).fillna(0))
```

Below is also close, but, since there are 500 different stocks in the df, when one stock ends and another begins, this is a problem.  Below works until you consider the overlapping stocks/tickers problem.  I can't figure out how to get groupby to work here.

```
    preceeding_5_day_perf = (df['adj_close'].shift(26) - df['adj_close'].shift(21)) / df['adj_close'].shift(21)
    df = df.assign(preceeding_5_day_perf=preceeding_5_day_perf)
```

A small sample of my dataframe:

```
Index     Date      High        Low         adj_close   Ticker daily_performance 21_day_performance one_month_6_pct+_gain
8930    2020-10-15  35.380001   33.639999   34.250000   UAL -0.038192   -0.105744                               No
8931    2000-01-03  18.625000   17.312500   10.834452   TROW    0.000000    0.000000                             No
8932    2000-01-04  17.562500   17.000000   10.506723   TROW    -0.030249   0.000000                             No
8933    2000-01-05  17.468750   16.593750   10.487448   TROW    -0.001835   0.000000                             No
8934    2000-01-06  17.500000   16.687500   10.795900   TROW    0.029412    0.000000                             No
8935    2000-01-07  17.750000   17.250000   10.718788   TROW    -0.007143   0.000000                             No
8936    2000-01-10  17.875000   17.437500   10.834452   TROW    0.010791    0.000000                             No
8937    2000-01-11  17.781250   17.281250   10.795900   TROW    -0.003558   0.000000                             No
8938    2000-01-12  18.250000   17.593750   11.258587   TROW    0.042858    0.000000                             No
8939    2000-01-13  19.843750   18.296875   11.875495   TROW    0.054794    0.000000                             No
8940    2000-01-14  19.562500   19.187500   12.048991   TROW    0.014610    0.000000                             No
8941    2000-01-18  19.437500   18.593750   11.586312   TROW    -0.038400   0.000000                             No
8942    2000-01-19  19.625000   18.812500   11.759820   TROW    0.014975    0.000000                             No
8943    2000-01-20  19.312500   18.875000   11.759820   TROW    0.000000    0.000000                             No
8944    2000-01-21  20.093750   19.187500   12.318892   TROW    0.047541    0.000000                             No
8945    2000-01-24  20.937500   19.625000   12.183943   TROW    -0.010955   0.000000                             No
8946    2000-01-25  21.250000   19.250000   13.070749   TROW    0.072785    0.000000                             No
8947    2000-01-26  21.312500   19.812500   12.955079   TROW    -0.008850   0.000000                             No
8948    2000-01-27  21.437500   19.593750   12.106827   TROW    -0.065476   0.000000                             No
8949    2000-01-28  19.687500   18.187500   11.258587   TROW    -0.070063   0.000000                             No
8950    2000-01-31  19.437500   17.937500   11.991161   TROW    0.065068    0.000000                             No
8951    2000-02-01  19.656250   18.687500   12.068275   TROW    0.006431    0.000000                             No
8952    2000-02-02  19.875000   19.000000   12.222500   TROW    0.012779    0.128114                             Yes
8953    2000-02-03  20.062500   18.750000   11.856213   TROW    -0.029968   0.128441                             Yes
8954    2000-02-04  19.375000   18.406250   11.451367   TROW    -0.034146   0.091912                             Yes
8955    2000-02-07  19.406250   18.281250   11.316417   TROW    -0.011785   0.048214                             No
8956    2000-02-08  18.625000   18.250000   11.316417   TROW    0.000000    0.055755                             No
8957    2000-02-09  18.750000   17.812500   11.085073   TROW    -0.020443   0.023132                             No
8958    2000-02-10  18.437500   17.750000   11.007962   TROW    -0.006956   0.019643                             No
8959    2000-02-11  18.000000   17.500000   10.824816   TROW    -0.016638   -0.038528                            No
8960    2000-02-14  17.718750   16.593750   10.391053   TROW    -0.040071   -0.125000                            No
```

​

Comment: @Stripedbass - thanks for taking a look.  The 21 days aren't shifted.  I'm trying to create a column for the 5 day performance prior to the 21 days.  This wouldn't be difficult if the df only had one stock.  But, with 500 stocks, I run into problems with shift when a row changes from one stock to another (eg. UAL to TROW in the above sample of my df).  Because of the 500 stocks problem, I think I need to use groupby but I can't figure out how to make that work with shift.  I'm now thinking I may deconstruct my df into individual stocks, perform what I need to perform,  and then concact.

Comment: The 21 days are the target in my model.  So, the 5 days prior to those 21 days can't be inclusive of the 21 day performance.  I'm not deleting, just creating a column that shifts rows (or, is a rolling window) for the starting and end point.  The second block of code that I included in the initial question is very close to what I want to accomplish.  But, I want to take the pct_change of one period to the next rather than summing the daily performance.

Comment: @Stripedbass - I think that would work for the column that I outlined. However, I excluded some of the scope of my model for simplicity sake. One column that I'm going to include is similar to the "preceeding_5_day_perf" column, but, it'll be "preceeding_15_year_perf" instead. So, the deletion of rows would wipe out 75% of my data if I add "preceeding_15_year_perf" with your suggestion. So, I want to avoid deleting rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem by creating new dataframes.  I'm sure there is a better solution.

```
    #creating an array of tickers
    unique_tickers = df.Ticker.unique()
    #creating a dictionary to be used in a for loop
    companydict = {elem : pd.DataFrame() for elem in unique_tickers}
    for key in companydict.keys():
        companydict[key] = df[:][df.Ticker == key]
        #creating the 5 day performance column that preceeds the 21 day prediction period
        preceeding_5_day_perf = (companydict[key]['adj_close'].shift(21) - companydict[key]['adj_close'].shift(26)) / companydict[key]['adj_close'].shift(26)
        companydict[key] = companydict[key].assign(preceeding_5_day_perf=preceeding_5_day_perf).fillna(0)
    #creating a new df for each ticker (eg. CSCO ticker will be in df_CSCO)
    globals()['df_{}'.format(key)] = companydict[key]
```

Then, I just created a list of all of the dfs and used concat to combine all of the dataframes vertically.

```
    df_final = pd.concat(df_list)
```

If pct_change() was supported after rolling() in Pandas, this would've been much easier.